# Using $.when() and .then to update an array based on $.getJSON responses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update array values using the response from multiple getJSON requests. I have tried this a number of ways and the snippet below is the simplest form I have used. The individual success callbacks have not updated the array by the time the .then() fires so the alert shows the original values. I have also tried to store the individual jqXHR objects in an array and work through them, but they are all readyState: 1. Any suggestions on how to get a reference to the responses after they have all completed?

```
$(function() {

    var points = [['A', 12946],
                  ['B', 4223],
                  ['C', 2774],
                 ];

    function makePointCalls(i) {
        return $.getJSON("http://otter.topsy.com/searchcount.json?callback=?",
            {
                q: points[i][0]
            },
            function(data) {
                points[i][1] = data.response.d;
            }
        );
    }

    $.when($.each(points, function(i, value){
              makePointCalls(i);
            })
        ).then(function(){
            //alert me after all the getJSONs are done and array updated?
            alert(points);
        });
});//doc ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs to react on the return value of `makePointCalls` which is discarded in your `each` loop.

Untested code fragments follow (working according to kas673's comment):

```
// Collect deferreds first
var deferreds = jQuery.map(points, function(i, value){
    return makePointCalls(i);
});

// Pass all deferreds to when
jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, deferreds).then(…);
```

Note the use of `map` instead of `each` to create an array with the return values (deferreds) of `makePointCalls`. The call to `apply` for invoking `when` is there to ensure `when` receives its [parameters in the documented format](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). If you would pass an array to `when` as sole argument it could just assume it received an resolved deferred and execute the function in `then` immediately.

A more verbose explanation regarding the use of apply is that `when` assumes everything is a resolved deferred that is not a deferred. First of all one needs to note that a deferred is some sort of callback manager. It holds callbacks to invoke on success/resolve and callbacks for failure/rejection. Deferreds are used to provide a return value for which it is only known at a later time whether the function invocation was successful. An example is your AJAX request that needs to wait for the server but should not block the JavaScript execution.

Each of your calls to `$.getJSON` returns a deferred which can be used to react on the requests completion. `$.when` takes any number of deferreds as its arguments and invokes `then`'s argument as soon as the aggregate state of the deferreds is known (either when all arguments to `when` are resolved or at least one was rejected).

Calling `$.when(deferreds).then(callback)` leads to immediate invocation of `callback` as mentioned before when `deferreds` as an array of `Deferred` objects. Calling `$.when(deferred[0], deferred[1]).then(callback)` does invoke `callback` when the aggregate state is known. Using `apply` allows you to unpack the array and use each element in the array as a parameter to the function on which `apply` is invoked (that's `when` in your case).

Check your ActiveX notifications again since Firebug runs in Firefox where ActiveX is fortunately not supported. Anything related to ActiveX there is probably because you are using a Microsoft-only API which you should not do.

Comment: This worked for me. I still don't understand the significance of passing the jQuery arg in .apply(). Also had some weird ActiveXObject notifications start coming up in firebug, but the app is functional. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$.each(...)` with `$.map(...).get()`, and, replace `makePointCalls(i)` with `return makePointCalls(i)`

```
$(function() {

    var points = [['A', 12946],
                  ['B', 4223],
                  ['C', 2774],
                 ];

    function makePointCalls(i) {
        return $.getJSON("http://otter.topsy.com/searchcount.json?callback=?",
            {
                q: points[i][0]
            },
            function(data) {
                points[i][1] = data.response.d;
            }
        );
    }

    $.when($.map(points, function(i, value){
              return makePointCalls(i);
            }).get();
        ).then(function(){
            //alert me after all the getJSONs are done and array updated?
            alert(points);
        });
});//doc ready
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with that chained .get(). Can you elaborate on that part. It seems redundant to me. All kinds of syntax issues, but I am pushing the limits of firebug's capabilities. When I first used your snippet I was able to break on the getJSON callback, but never again. I also had to switch the args in the .map callback.